# How to traverse a tree with many levels to find the previous and next element of the current element?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do i find the previous and next element of any given element in a tree that has sublists?

Example

1. A

   1.1 AA

   1.1.1 AAA

   1.1.2 BBB

   1.1.3 CCC

1.2 DD

How do i get the previous and next id's of 1.1.3 CCC ? I only know the ID of CCC at the given moment.

The real example i am working with is a Category entity which has a recursive association to itself because it can contain SubCategories. If i am in a level 3 subcategory, i would like to know the ID of the previous and next Category.

In my View (webpage) i have a list of all the categories. When i click on a Category, i only know it's own id, but would like to get the previous and next id aswell.

I've used the following methods but they dont work when there a more levels:

```
private void GetNextCategoryID(PagedData<ShowQuestionViewModel> questionsPaged)
    {

        List<Category> categories = db.Category.Where(y => y.parrent_id == null).ToList();

        categories.Sort(new CompareCategory());

        List<ShowCategoriesViewModel> scvm = Mapper.Map<List<Category>, List<ShowCategoriesViewModel>>(categories);

        for (int i = 0; i < scvm.Count; i++)
        {
            if (scvm[i].category_id == questionsPaged.CategoryID)
            {
                if (scvm[i].SubCategories != null && scvm[i].SubCategories.Count > 0)
                {                          
                        questionsPaged.NextCategory_ID = scvm[i].SubCategories.First().category_id;
                        break;                   
                }

                try
                {
                    questionsPaged.NextCategory_ID = scvm[i + 1].category_id;
                    break;
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                {
                    questionsPaged.NextCategory_ID = 0;
                    break;
                }

            }
            else if (scvm[i].SubCategories != null)
            {
                for (int q = 0; q < scvm[i].SubCategories.Count; q++)
                {
                    if (scvm[i].SubCategories[q].category_id == questionsPaged.CategoryID)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            questionsPaged.NextCategory_ID = scvm[i].SubCategories[q + 1].category_id;
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                        {
                            // Betyder at vi er kommet til den sidste kategori i rækken
                            // og at den endnu ikke har fundet en match

                            try
                            {
                                questionsPaged.NextCategory_ID = scvm[i + 1].category_id;
                                break;

                            }
                            catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException eq)
                            {
                                // Dette betyder at den valgte underkategori kategori er den sidste i spørgeskemaet
                                questionsPaged.NextCategory_ID = 0;
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and

```
private void GetPreviousCategoryID(PagedData<ShowQuestionViewModel> questionsPaged)
    {
        List<Category> categories = db.Category.Where(y => y.parrent_id == null).ToList();
        categories.Sort(new CompareCategory());
        List<ShowCategoriesViewModel> scvm = Mapper.Map<List<Category>, List<ShowCategoriesViewModel>>(categories);

        for (int i = scvm.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (scvm[i].category_id == questionsPaged.CategoryID)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (scvm[i - 1].SubCategories != null)
                    {
                        int subcount = scvm[i - 1].SubCategories.Count;
                        questionsPaged.PreviousCategory_ID = scvm[i - 1].SubCategories[subcount - 1].category_id;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        questionsPaged.PreviousCategory_ID = scvm[i - 1].category_id;
                    }

                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
                {
                    questionsPaged.CategoryID = scvm[i].category_id;
                    break;
                }
            }

            else if (scvm[i].SubCategories != null)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < scvm[i].SubCategories.Count; x++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (scvm[i].SubCategories[x].category_id == questionsPaged.CategoryID)
                        {

                            questionsPaged.PreviousCategory_ID = scvm[i].SubCategories[x - 1].category_id;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException qx)
                    {
                        questionsPaged.PreviousCategory_ID = scvm[i].category_id;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: So a tree node holds a category and each node can have any number of children right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, what you should do is this: with the id of the current category, traverse the tree until you find the node with that id. Once here, to find the successor (I'm assuming the successor is to the right) you must go back up the tree: if the parent has a right child, find the leftmost node of the subtree rooted at that child, otherwise, apply this reasoning recursively to the parent of the parent and so on.

To find the predecessor, just do the above steps but check if the parent has a left child and find the righmost node of that subtree, or apply recursively to the parent of the parent.

```
// finds the successor of node
procedure successor(node) 
{
    // assuming you have the node for the id that you know.
    // also I'm assuming you have some way to find its position 
    // in the child list

    // if the parent has a child to the right
    if(parent(node).children[position(node) + 1] != null)
    {
        return findLeftmost(parent(node).children[position(node) + 1]);
        // find the leftmost node in the subtree rooted 
        // at the next sibling to the  right
    }
    else
    {
        return successor(parent(node));
        // move up the tree
    }
}


// finds the leftmost leaf node of the (sub)tree rooted at node
procedure findLeftmost(node)
{
    if(node.children.length == 0) // leaf node
    {
        return node;
    }
    else
    {
        return findLeftmost(node.children[0]); 
        // here I'm assuming the children are in the list from left to right, 
        // such that children[0] is the leftmost child.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really a tree but a list, but i get your point. I will try to get it to work and get back to you.

Comment: except categories come before their own children, so going to the right you only need to look  at your own first child, or "top-level" sibling.  Going to the left (previous), you'd still have to follow this logic.

Comment: Ok, it's not very in-detail, but it's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understood your question so apologies in advance if this is the case.

It appears to me that you have the index within your list of a node, and you know its level, and you therefore simply need to skip over previous or next nodes in the view that have a greater level (i.e. they are child nodes) until you find one with an equal (and therefore sibling) level, or a lower level or you run out of nodes, in which case there is no sibling at that level.

Comment: I dont actually have the index within a list, i just have the database ID of the element, so i dont know it's level either. I can see the level on my website, because it creates a tree, but when i click on the Category, all i have is it's id.